# Does the site have internal "engine" to scale Retina images?

Tags: feature-request

There is a frequent issue with retina screenshots - they looks huge because of their resolution and I constantly have to resize the files. In iOS there is a sign for the OS to show that the image is of retina quality (I mean @2x in the name of the file).

Does the GD-site have something similar? Is it possible to include this convention to the interface of the site?

Comment: I woukd ask this on meta but I do not think so.

Comment: I think just the fact that retina images upload as very large would indicate that the image upload does not generate the 2x or 3x sizes.

Comment: You can use `<img>` tags with a `width`.

Comment: A lazy option is just to take extra-wide screengrabs - more whitespace on either side - then the max width will scale them down. But that does make them smaller than ideal when the site is viewed on mobile.